# Would it be a security compromise to place the object exported from socket.io-client on the window object?

Tags: security, socket.io, cypress, websecurity

Motivation: I'm trying to test my (React) app using Cypress.
Although Cypress supports http mocking OOTB, it does not support Websockets mocking and moreover socket.io is not supported.
Instead they recommend accessing (and possibly stubbing) a global `window.io`.
So the question is: Is it safe to do something like:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
window.io = io;
```

in the production code.
PS - the client authenticate itself by sending a token to the server and all is done over wss.